# .html() jQuery method bizzare bug - resolves to empty space locally, but not on production

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-app-engine

I'm making a simple jquery command:

`element.html("&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;");`

using the attributes/html method:  http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html

It works on my local app engine server, but it doesn't work once I push to the Google server. The element empties but doesn't fill with spaces.

So instead of `"      "` *(6 spaces)* it's just `""`.

Once again, this is running on App Engine, but I don't think that should matter...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try generating the space during run-time, so it won't be trimmed or whatever happens during transport:

```
element.html(String.fromCharCode(32));
```

Answer (score 3):

This might not be a direct answer to your problem, but why are you even wanting to put in a heap of spaces? You can probably achieve the same result by just changing the `padding-left` or `text-indent` of that element.

```
element.css("textIndent", "3em");
```

Using a heap of `&nbsp;`s is a very dodgy way to do indentation.

Answer (score 2):

Your jQuery should look like this:

```
$('element').html('&nbsp;&nbsp;');
```

... where '`&nbsp;`' equals once space.

(with however many spaces you want, of course)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `&nbsp;` instead of spaces? The `html()` method just pumps the string into the innerHTML of the element(s).

Answer (score 0):

Is there a possibility that the code is minified as part of the process of being deployed onto the App Engine?

I would not expect any string of whitespace to be retained as written, perhaps you could actually escape the white space and force any minification to leave it:

example:

```
element.html('\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ');
```